# Raphael piechart legend font

Tags: raphael, font-size, legend

The legend in my piechart is too small ... how can I make it text size bigger. Following is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="g.raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="g.pie-min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      var r = Raphael("holder");
      pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [10,20,0,0],
            {
              legend: ["%% Unknown","%% Recognisable","%% Familiar","%% Known"],
              colors: ["#FF0000","#FFB2B2","#CCFFCC","#00E600"], 
              legendpos: "west"
            });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the legend in g.Raphael isn't that configurable. If you want more control over it, you might want to build the legend yourself. See [this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/451637) for an example of how to do this.

When you have your legend in place, control the font size as follows:

```
t = paper.text(x, y, 'Data set 1');
t.attr({ 'font-size': 24 });
```